# unused expression, expected an assignment or function call Angular lint error in promise function

Tags: angular, eslint, lint

when i run lint command in angular 8, i have some error in lint results like

> Error: unused expression, expected an assignment or function call

```
  new Promise((resolve) => {
  this.doclistCheck(data.cusType);
  resolve();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the "no-unused-expression" tslint rule. 
Try this,

```
  const _promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    this.doclistCheck(data.cusType);
    resolve();
  });
```

Comment: i got error like variable name must be in lowerCamelCase, PascalCase or UPPER_CASE . and i solved when removing underscore before promise. Done! thanks!

Comment: but now i'm getting another tslint error of unused variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this you get error like

> variable name must be in lowerCamelCase, PascalCase or UPPER_CASE

**Actual Code:**

```
const _promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
this.doclistCheck(data.cusType);
resolve();
```

});

**Change To** remove the underscore before promise in line one

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
this.doclistCheck(data.cusType);
resolve();
```

});